# LTE ASN.1 BCCH - LD - SCH Messages Decoder

Tags: c#, asn.1

With great difficulty, I'm trying to implement a parser for reading sib codes and analyzing cells tower. I convert a particular ASN.1 EUTRA_RRC_Definitions structure in a C# DLL. In theory I can decode the code and get a file XML structured.
I searched everywhere online for examples, but I found nothing.

This is my code that I'm trying to get it works:

```
    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                         .ToArray();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        BCCH_BCH_Message sib = new BCCH_BCH_Message();
        sib.Init();
        const string V = "694c4224198860c1312a984c031807c06e493ab212103108b4890000";
        var buffer = StringToByteArray(V);
        sib.Decode(new Com.Objsys.Asn1.Runtime.Asn1OerDecodeBuffer(buffer));
    }
}
```

I hope someone had already faced with this issue.

Comment: This is the exception I get: **Com.Objsys.Asn1.Runtime.Asn1Exception: 'base class decode method invoked'**

Comment: I already tried in the online decoder **MARBEN ASN.1** , by setting up RRC (BCCH-LD-SCH-MESSAGE) and it works! I don't know why in others decoders it doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error as well as what you attempted. Don't post them in the comments.